# ChildBrowser in a non-mobile browser, for testing/debugging

Tags: cordova, webview, childbrowser, ripple

I am writing a PhoneGap/Cordova app and am using the **ChildBrowser** plugin to open pages similar to a WebView in iOS or Android. I often test my web pages on my local browser (usually Chrome) because viewing my page locally is much faster than deploying it onto a device or emulator. Using a browser also allows me to take advantage of debugging tools such as Chrome's Inspect feature or Firefox's Firebug plugin.

The issue is that the ChildBrowser plugin will not work on a non-mobile platform. Is there any work-around out there to allow me to test ChildBrowser before deploying it to a device/emulator?

BTW, using **Ripple** did not work for me because ChildBrowser is not yet supported by Ripple.

Comment: Why the downvote? It is a valid question

Comment: I'd upgrade to 2.3.0 and use InAppBrowser which is controlled via window.open() which will work on any browser.

Answer (score 1):

I would use the device model to detect what's opening the page, put an if statement to say if it's not a phone device then open the page normally and bypass childbrowser.

http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.3.0/cordova_device_device.model.md.html#device.model